# Two div same height responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, fluid-layout

Hello I write some script but i think it need some fix to work properly.
My target is to set .height-driven to the same value as .height-driver but need to work also when resizing. after you resize window everything is ok but on load jQuery(window).resize(); not load so i need to TIMEOUT it other case it wont work You can see it after 2sec when RUN script and have width of window more than 768px.  how to call this function without delay??

when you remove delay and put just jQuery(window).resize(); it will work here but on website sometimes You have to refresh it 4,5,6 times becouse it set .height-driven height to 0px
alternate version work on jsfiddle but not in real page : http://jsfiddle.net/2Lod0sxq/

actual version:
http://jsfiddle.net/ponciusz/z818ehxt/

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
// resize after resizing
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){  
        //if less than 768 set heignt auto
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            jQuery('.height-driven').css({"height": "auto" });  
        }
        // if bigger run
        else {
            jQuery('.height-driven').each(function(){             
                var ka_height = jQuery('.height-driver').height();
                jQuery(this).css({"height": ka_height });      
            })
        }
    }) 
    // after page load check if less 768 if yes set height to auto
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        jQuery('.height-driven').css({"height": "auto" });
    }
    // if more resize after 1 sec - IF DELETE THIS SET HEIGHT WONT WORK after refresh
    else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(window).resize();
        }, 2000);             
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
    <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin="">
        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
            <div class="uk-panel uk-vertical-align height-driven service-wrap">
                <div class="uk-vertical-align-middle ka_fade service-content">
                    <h2>LOREM</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodoconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-width-medium-1-2">
            <div class="uk-panel height-driver">
                <img class="uk-align-center" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x700/000/fff" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i've done this on my page too... but different. i created a resize function, that get's called on dom ready and on windo resize.
i put the window.resize() part out of the dom ready part - so that this is on the same lvl...

Comment: Can You explain it with some sample code sorry but i am not advenced programmer.

Comment: So to get this straight: You want the image to be the same height as the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

i replaced first line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

to this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
```

and now working perfect.